# SUMIFS combine with LARGE

Tags: excel, if-statement, largenumber

Is there a way to combine "LARGE" with "IF"?

My Large formula is working, but if I want to Combine it with "IF", I don't know, how to solve it. The Problem is that I have named an Area in the data set with "Area1" and different names in it. I want for "Name1", which is in the "Area1" several times, the highest value he can find in another named area,"Area2".

Hope you understand my Problem and can help me out :)

Comment: maxifs or aggregate not working for you?

Comment: As far as I know, maxifs does not work for Excel 2010 and with aggregate, I never seen, how to implement something like an if criteria. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Your question is far too vague to offer a suggestion.

Comment: I want to have the highest 10 values of a certain "column1", but only of these values, with "text1" in "column2" written and need a formula for that. Maybe it sums up better, if not tell me your question :)